# properly checking null values in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, trello

So I have been researching this question for days now and can't seem to find an answer that actually works. I am dealing with an api (trello to be specific) that when providing back json objects places a NULL value in attributes that do not have a value. I am parsing through the data after getting it from the api and need a way to skip the null values or delete them. For example here is a part of an object with a null value:

```
{ name: 'blah',
  due: null,
  cards: [ [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
 [ [Object] ],
 [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
 null,
 [ [Object], [Object] ],
 [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
 [ [Object], [Object] ],
 [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ] }
```

The due attribute is used as an override for the date timestamp pulled elsewhere. Right now I am using this which seems to work:

```
if (!update.due) {
    update.lastUpdated = update.history[0].date;
} else {
    update.lastUpdated = update.due;
}
```

Is this the only proper way to check for a null value? its the only way I have found to work consistently. Also, when deleting values from an object is there a way I could check so I could then just remove the attribute altogether?:

```
"if Obj[attr] === null"
```

Comment: I mean, null will always be falsey, but you could instead check if it is null `if (update.due === null)` so that you won't get false positives (or negatives, however you look at it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether or not you can use the shortcut `if (!update.due)` rather than `if (update.due !== null)` depends upon the range of values that could be in `update.due` and what you want the result of the test to be for that range of values.

---

In Javascript, you can check for a specific value with `===` or you can allow type conversions with `==` of you can check if any truthy or falsey value.

When you do:

```
if (!update.due)
```

you are checking to see if `update.due` is any falsey value.  Falsey values include `null`, `""`, `0`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined`.

If all you're trying to do is to see if `update.due` has some non-zero value numeric or boolean value in it, then `if (!update.due)` is compact and does the job just fine.

On the other-hand, if you really want to know unequivocably whether it contains `null` or not, then you have to test specifically for `null` like this:

```
if (update.due !== null)
```

Since `if (!update.due)` is shorter, it is very commonly used to just check if there's some defined value in `update.due`.  You do have to be careful that `0` is not a valid value for you because `null` and `0` would give the same result with this particular test.  But as long as the values you're testing for would not be empty strings or zero, then `if (!update.due)` works just fine.

Comment: Great explanation, I just wasn't sure that I could actually check against null itself. Thanks!